# Trying to run two simultaneous loops that do the same task with different delay cycles

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to control a pellet stove auger motor in such a way that I can use a toggle switch to do High/Low (H/L) - so the way that I have it now is:

```
 void setup() {
   // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(2850);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(11250);
```

Which is just LED on/off but it also controls another relay that controls the blower motor - what I'm trying to set up is a H setting that would be the 2850 delay-ON - and then have say: pin 11 have a delay-OFF of 7000, and have pin 13 still resetting to the delay-ON of 2850.

What I mean is:

- loop A: pin12 on -delay 2850 pin12 off -delay 11250
- loop B: pin13 on -delay 2850 pin13 off -delay 7000

I saw and tried the code for 'multi-blink' - as the one I use is pretty much modified 'blink'.

Any assistance would be awesome - I run the one I show above now, on my pellet stove and it was recently -31.4 and worked like a charm, but I'd like to be able to have a high/low option.

PS: I also have a coffee roaster control project as well... help on that one is always appreciated as well.

Comment: Just out of interest... -31.4°C or -31.4°F? Although they are pretty much close, and damned cold either way!

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino [Simple Timer library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer) (and other similar timer libraries) are made for exactly this kind of application. Your `setup()` routine calls the SimpleTimer library, naming a callback-function and how often it should get called. Your loop function must then call `timer.run()` reasonably frequently (where 
reasonably frequently" depends on the timing accuracy and jitter tolerance of your application). `timer.run()` will call each of your callback-functions at its appropriate time. You write the callback-functions to do whatever you need them to do when the timer calls them.

There are one-shot timers and repeating timers - it sounds like your application could one of each per LED: One that fires periodically, to to call a turn-on-LED12 function every (ON_TIME_12+OFF_TIME_12) ms, and a one-shot that calls a turn-off-LED12 function, started by the turn-on-LED_12 function for (ON_TIME_12) msec. Same for LED13, ( ..., etc.)

Your loop function is free to do whatever else, as long as it calls `timer.run()` frequently enough that your application can meet its timing requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the perfect example for [the simple scheduler](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler):

```
#include <Scheduler.h>

const int pinA = 12;
const int pinB = 13;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Scheduler.start(setupA, loopA);
  Scheduler.start(setupB, loopB);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print(millis());
  Serial.print(F(":pinA="));
  Serial.print(digitalRead(pinA));
  Serial.print(F(",pinB="));
  Serial.println(digitalRead(pinB));
  delay(1000);
}

void setupA()
{
  pinMode(pinA, OUTPUT);
}

void loopA()
{
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);
  delay(2850);
  digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);
  delay(11250);
}

void setupB()
{
  pinMode(pinB, OUTPUT);
}

void loopB()
{
  digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);
  delay(2850);
  digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);
  delay(7000);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Pretty amazing that only a couple of hours ago and now I have a written variant to try, which I tried something similar on the uno before, the code available at arduino for "multi-blink" but it wouldn't compile, but then i saw it said you needed a due, but not an uno to run it, but so didn't mess with it all that much, it made sense, but wouldn't run, and I failed to copy the error, but i'll def try running this, with pins of course, is there any reason it wouldn't run on a mega as well? The uno is busy keeping me warm, but I have a mega here, so I'll try that first

Comment: The Scheduler library above (lhttps://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler) can be used with more or less all Arduino boards. It gives the illusion of running multiple sketches in the same sketch.

Comment: I'm sorry man, i'm pretty sure i'm a dunce at this point - i tried all the ways i could find to include that and a different one as well, library, but still was unable to compile it = i don't get it, my understanding is that the code you posted would work with the library listed added - i'm certainly feeling shame in admitting I clearly don't know how to add a library to a sketch - help please.

Comment: Installing a library in Arduino is hard (at least the first time). Start by downloading the ZIP file from https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler. Locate the "libraries" folder in the Sketchbook (or Arduino folder). Unzip the Arduino-Scheduler-master into the "libraries" folder and rename the folder Scheduler. Restart the Arduino IDE and you are ready to go.

Comment: It definitely doesn't help that the pc i'm using to code/try to code with is a 2012 hp $250 laptop that, as someone that has used computers since 1986+/- , is the WORST computer ever - tried upgrading to win10 from 7 - which was working fine, but i suppose i'm a bit of an early adopter , then, no touch pad at all, ditched the thing for a bit and just used phone, then needed to program the A unit to make the pellet stove work, so tried again, now, my touch pad does work, but, if you use the keyboard there is a oh, one to 1.5 sec delay before the touchpad works again - not stellar equpiment,

Comment: oddly, the first time i tried it was a zip, and i put it where it was supposed to go - i do try to follow directions most of the time (and do also mock those that don't), then i tried the rest of the options that were made available - i finally got it to say there was a , that was unexpected or some similar error, then pc was rebooted before getting the error copied - at this point... i don't get why it wont compile, it seems all the files are where they should be and the code makes sense, but...

Comment: WARNING: library Scheduler claims to run on [sam architecture(s) and may be incompatible with your current board which runs on samd] architecture(s).